# Axlsx automatic chart size

Tags: ruby-on-rails, axlsx

I am using the axlsx and axlsx_rails gem,
I want to know if there is a way to set the chart (ex: Bar3DChart) size automatically.

Now I am using the "fixed" way using `start_at` and `end_at`

```
sheet.add_chart(Axlsx::Bar3DChart, :start_at => "A1", :end_at => "M40")
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I imagine that you check docu: [Bar3DChart](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/randym/axlsx/Axlsx/Bar3DChart), I always use the "fixed" way too due to reviewing this I diidn't find an easy way.

Nothing on docu inside 3DChart and nothing on [Chart](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/randym/axlsx/Axlsx/Chart) docu in general. The only methods provided are :start_at, end_at. There are no other way regarding docu.

Regars

Comment: Thanks, I thought that too. Now I am just making the value of ```end_at``` dynamic